# How to test 500 Trillion combinations in less than 6 hours of execution time

Tags: c#, java, php, execution-time

I have a PHP script now looping through combinations of a set of arrays.  I can test 6.1 Billion of the 500 Trillion total combinations in 1 hour with a simple PHP script.  Is it possible to write a program in any language running on todays average PC that would be able to test all 500 Trillion combinations of multiple arrays in less than ~6 hours?

Also, I do not have the resources to use distributed or cluster computing for this task.  What kind of gains could I expected converting the code to multithreaded java/c#?

Thank you

Comment: Is it a WPA 48 bits to hack? ;)

Comment: This hugely depends on the method you use to process those array elements and how much ram you're wasting to save those 500 trillion combinations. In theory yes, multithreaded languages could utilize CPU better.

Comment: if this is for a noble cause, you could create a "donate cpu time" page and go viral, collecting blocks of solution done by users in their browser... that would solve your resources problem...

Comment: Depending on the algorithm, you can avoid using brute force and cut the number of combinations you need to consider by many orders of magnitude. e.g. find a combination of an array which sums to a total.  If you use brute force you add up every combination and see if it matches the total.  A simple optimisation is to sum all but one and see if the `total-sumSoFar` is a member of the array/set. (As when you add this you will have the total)  Combinations which involve duplicates can be optimised so you don't have to consider the duplicate combinations.

Comment: Wouldn't this question fit Programmers.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start simple. Do you use threading? If not - a modern higher end Intel today has 12 hardware threads per processor. This means you get a factor of 12 from threading.

If someone gets a server specific for that he could get 24-32 hardware threads easily for relatively low cost.

If the arrays are semi static and you asume adecent graphics card, you may find having from 800 to 3000 processor cores a huge time saver. Nothing beats this - and even average CPU's have quite some core capabilities in their chips or the graphics cards these days.

Comment: I agree with TomTom - GPGPU-Computing is definitly the way to go in such cases and if you do not have the resources for clustering or similar.

Comment: Even if. There isa  reason SuperMicro sells 2 rack unit servers with space for 6 Nvidia Tesla cards. NOTHING beats GPU for paralellizable operations. I know a guy making options analysis on the US stock markets with a machine under his desk - every second, ALL stocks. Uses a coupld of 6990 for that.

Comment: @TomTom nothing beats GPGPU for a specific kind of parallel operations. In this case yes it should be quite a good fit.

Comment: It looks like the simple answer is NO, with my options being parallel processing in GPU or cluster computing.  Thanks to all.

Comment: @QBawl The simple answer is NO, but depending on what assumptions you can make you can eliminate many of the combinations and reduce it by several orders of magnitude and get the time down to a second in some case. e.g. Some Project Euler problems are like this.  Use brute force and it can take hours. Be smart about it and it can take seconds.

Answer (score 3):

```
500 trillion comparisons in 6 hours
=
83.3 trillion comparisons in 1 hour
=
1.4 trillion comparisons per minute
=
23.1 billion comparisons per second
```

Assuming you've got an Intel Core i7-2600 cpu (3.4GHz), which is 4 cores + hyperthreading = 8 cores, you'd need a per-core speed of

```
23.1/6 = 3.9GHz
```

which is at the extreme end of possibility for basic overclocking.

Once you factor in other overhead, what you want is not possible. Your cpu cannot do NOTHING BUT COMPARISONS.

Comment: reserving 2 cores for overhead?

Comment: I'm not even sure if HT with such a task. And then the account here is missing something: 3.9billion comparisons don't map directly to 1 cycle/comparison. Depending on the actual code we'll need a whole lot more for getting the next necessary combination, looping overhead and so on. I'd be pretty surprised if we'd get by with less than at least a hundred cycles per iteration

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have the resources then I'm afraid to say, with the numbers you want, you are buggered.

You'll need to rethink your data structures and the algorithms working on them to have any chance of completing your puzzle within the time limit - using PHP or any other language.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about the process you want to run and maybe there is no way to achieve your goals with your current resources, but since you are asking for a language, and it is true that PHP is not the best one to tackle paralelism, I should say that Erlang is famous for that kind of achievements.